# How to Securely Outsource Proof of Work Calculation?

Tags: pow, internet-of-things

In another question about proof of work on Internet of Things devices [one answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/75/334) mentions *"it would be capable of outsourcing PoW within it's local area network"*. This piques my interest. How is outsourcing the PoW done securely?

**Premise:** Use of very cheap (every cent counts), battery powered (every watt counts) IoT sensors  which are incapable of any complex calculation they just measure stuff and send it somewhere. They do not calculate anything. Think of a temperature sensor which periodically sends a simple temperature value via some sort of wireless low power protocol.

How would the setup look like to employ IOTA to support the integrity of these values?

Comment: From your question it's unclear what risk arises from sharing non-PoWed transactions.

Comment: @Come-from-Beyond non-PoWed transactions are not transactions. They are messages, age old IT technology. If there's no workable way to secure transactions IOTA has failed it's base premise as *backbone for the Internet of Things.*

Comment: OK, wasn't sure about the terminology you had used.

Answer (score 2):

The outsourcing of POW for light clients is already default. The `attachToTangle` command on the IRI does the POW and all public nodes (e.g. `http://iota.bitfinex.com:80`) **manually** deactivated it  because they don't want to do the POW for all the light wallets.

## Security

The signing can be done independently of the POW so there is no security issue at all (except [this one](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/382/what-prevents-a-malicious-node-from-receiving-a-transaction-and-instead-of-rela/383#383))

## Small sensors

[image: image description]
The sensors (orange) can just send their data to the your own full node (green). Your full node then builds the transaction, signs it and broadcasts it to its neighbours (pink).

If the green node is not owned by you (or it is but you just don't want to do the signing), the sensor has to build the transaction, sign it and send them to the green node which does the POW and broadcasts it to the neighbours.

Comment: So there's nothing helping me secure that last bit. That makes IOTA only useful for wherever I can set up my full node in front of my IoT devices. Which is likely not very helpful for most IoT use cases...

Comment: It doesn't matter how far the full node is away from the sensor. They just need to be able to communicate with each other. And if a sensor can't communicate with "the internet" it's useless anyway.

Comment: Communicating and communicating securely are two entirely different things...

Comment: Let me rephrase: A sensor that can't communicate securely with "the internet" is useless anyway.